# Automating Refresh of Graphs using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, chart.js, setinterval

I am creating an analytics of my Facebook bot, it contains the frequency of the commands that is being used and the RAM status of the server, both displayed as graph on the server-side web, I am using Replit btw. The graph works well but I need to refresh every time to see the update of the graphs how can I update the data of the graphs without refreshing the webpage, here's the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Chart = require('chart.js');

app.get('/memory-data', (req, res) => {
  const memoryData = {
    rss: process.memoryUsage().rss,
    heapTotal: process.memoryUsage().heapTotal,
    heapUsed: process.memoryUsage().heapUsed,
    external: process.memoryUsage().external
  };
  const maxRam = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32 MB
  Object.keys(memoryData).forEach(key => {
    memoryData[key] = Math.round(memoryData[key] / maxRam * 100);
  });
  res.json(memoryData);
});

app.get('/chart-data', (req, res) => {
  const chartData = {};
  const analyticsDir = __dirname + '/analytics/';
  fs.readdirSync(analyticsDir).forEach(file => {
    const name = file.replace('.txt', '');
    const content = fs.readFileSync(analyticsDir + file, 'utf8');
    const value = parseInt(content);
    chartData[name] = value;
  });
  res.json(chartData);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/chart');
});

app.get('/chart', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #161616;
      }
      .chart-container {
        width: 80%;
        height: 40vh;
      }
      .chart {
        background-color: #262626;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="chart-container; height:40vh; width:80vw;">
      <canvas id="myChart" class="chart"></canvas>
      <canvas id="myCircleChart" class="chart" style="margin-top: 20px;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
      // Code for the first chart
      function updateChartData() {
        $.get('/chart-data', function(data) {
          var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
          var colors = 'rgba(32, 213, 210, 1.0)';
          var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: Object.keys(data),
              datasets: [{
                label: 'Command Frequency',
                data: Object.values(data),
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                borderWidth: 0
              }]
            },
            options: {
              plugins: {
                legend: {
                  labels: {
                    color: "white",
                    font: {
                      size: 18 
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              scales: {
                y: {
                  grid: {
                    color: 'grey'
            },
            ticks: {
              color: 'white'
            }, 
            beginAtZero: true
          },
          x: {
            grid: {
              color: 'grey'
            },
            ticks: {
              color: 'white'
            },
            barPercentage: 0.6,
            categoryPercentage: 0.7
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

setInterval(updateChartData, 1000);

 function updateMemoryData() {
  $.get('/memory-data', function(data) {
    var colors = ['rgba(32, 213, 210, 1.0)', 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1.0)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)', 'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1.0)' ];
    var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myCircleChart').getContext('2d'), {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['RSS', 'Heap Total', 'Heap Used', 'External'],
        datasets: [{
          data: [
            data.rss,
            data.heapTotal,
            data.heapUsed,
            data.external
          ],
          backgroundColor: colors,
          borderColor: 'black'
        }]
      },
      options: {
         cutout: 90,
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              font: {
                size: 18
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });

    chart.data.datasets[0].data = Object.values(data);
    chart.update();
  });
}

setInterval(updateMemoryData, 1000);
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


  `);
});


const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

As you can see in the code I tried to use setInterval, but it's not working, maybe something's wrong with the arrangement of my code, I am just beginning to learn these things so I can't figure out what's wrong